# trainCascadeObjectDetector seems to be missing from MATLAB R2012b

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I wish to use trainCascadeObjectDetector to train on new objects (other than faces); I have the Computer Vision Toolkit installed; but this function trainCascadeObjectDetector seems to be missing from my system. Did I miss something during installation? Or has this been removed from R2012b?

Comment: Since this question is entirely about the matlab toolbox, and not about actual signal processing, this site probably isn't the best fit for this question.

Comment: is there a way to integrate this function in matlab 2011?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [release notes for the computer vision toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/release-notes.html), it looks like that functionality was not added until the R2013a release.